# how to customize django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have a two field in models.py

```
password_protected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to write admin.py in such a manner:

-- if password_protected is True: Then the password field should be enable.
-- if password_protected is False: Then the password field should be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can try what @luc suggested, but you can also try adding a widget to `password_protected` field:

```
password = models.CharField(default=False, widget=forms.TextInput())
```

-- and adjust its attributes:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # do some nice stuff here
else:
    if form['password_protected'].data:
        form.fields['password_protected'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
```

Note that specifying that `widget` for `password` field should be unnecessary, as fields have default widgets, but I added it in case it's required to modify widget attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easier way is to implement this behavior with javascript and jquery. The fields can be accessed by their name with jquery (for example something like `$("input[name=password]");`.

Then you can insert your js file into the admin by adding [Media class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions) into the admin class.

I hope it helps